# Newline character is ignored by Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

When I'm trying to write a string `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \n<response list="true">\n <audio>\n  <aid>412317542</aid>\n`... to a new .xml file, it gets written as a *single line*, ignoring all `\n` characters.

Why is it happening, and how do I get *several lines*?

My code:

```
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read()    # Here I get the xml data
with open('output.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(str(html))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string looks like is [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes), so you should use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), not just [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

```
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read()    # Here I get the xml data

with open('output.xml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html.decode(page.headers.get_content_charset()))
```